# I cant start my docker in Linux mint

Tags: docker

```
[myshell]# sudo dockerd
Error starting daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

In linux, I installed docker but daemon is not running. 
the above given error is always generated.

Answer (score 0):

Check If you already have the Docker Installed in it.
May be The Installation was not proper.
Check this [Link](http://linuxbsdos.com/2016/12/13/how-to-install-docker-and-run-docker-containers-on-linux-mint-1818-1/)

Answer (score 0):

if you

```
cat /var/run/docker.pid
```

it is mostly likely you are already running it.
you can take a look at the official and proper way to launch your docker once it is installed
https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/